# Renaming ActiveX ComboBoxes in an existing worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, properties, activex

I have a question for which don't find code snippets.

When an existing worksheet ActiveX combobox has been renamed using VBA, why does the workbook need to be reopened for its name property to fully refresh/sync?

Is there a workaround?

A comment on the external link below notes a similar issue:
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-how-to-change-the-name-of-an-existing-combobox.1082608/

In this use case, I loop through the OLEObjects collection and filtering specific OLEObjects into a standard collection. When I change the name property, I am referencing the standard collection items.

The name changes reflect on the worksheet but not in the backend properties of the OLEObjects until the workbook is closed and reopened.

Comment: How do you rename it?
When I tested it with `ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Name = "dsegf" ` and did it twice so 
`ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Name = "dsegf" 
ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Name = "dsegf" `
the name changed - strange

Comment: @redhare  In this particular use case, I am looping through the OLEObjects collection and filtering specific OLEObjects into a standard collection. Then when i change the name property, I am referencing the standard collection items.

Comment: @redhare Bump comment reply

Comment: @redhare Thank you for your help. Please see my posted answer. The situation was very much a one-off bug.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it appears in the example, my code was lacking something.  I was getting confused as to what was automatically occurring via Excel itself versus programmatically on my end.

UPDATE:
Another major cause of the problem, which I discovered via intensive debugging!!! If you rename any ActiveX combo box to include the "!" symbol, the boxes will experience issues when trying to communicate with any VBA events code - even after the boxes are renamed again later to not include such a symbol. Closing and reopening the workbook refreshes the bugs out of the combo boxes at that point.

If you try to add the "!" symbol to a regular event procedure name, you will receive an error. I am assuming this bug is inadvertently triggered by renaming the box to include that symbol. Warning: This may apply to other symbols but has not been tested. My situation was very unique in this case.

Another important point to emphasize: if your code involves renaming ActiveX combo boxes and any two or more boxes share the same name at some point throughout the code, this will cause a bug with any events code listening in the worksheet module until the workbook is closed/reopened. This bug occurs even if no two boxes share the same property name by the end of the procedure.